# Not getting SQL ID Text values from table usin jsoup

Tags: html, tags, jsoup

HTML Content:

```
<table id="list-table" class="list">
<tbody id="list-tbody">
<tr>
<td class="label">
<span class="header">SQL ID: 7w1ahss5vuwv4</span>
<br><b>Executions: </b>5<br><b>Total Execution Time: </b>4 ms<br><b>Maximum Execution Time: </b>1 ms<br><b>Average Execution Time: </b>1 ms
</td>
<td class="text">
<pre class="line-clip line-clip-9" id="sql0" sqlid="SQL ID: 7w1ahss5vuwv4">SELECT * FROM (SELECT FndDocumentEntitiesDTEO.<wbr>DOCUMENT_ENTITY_ID, </pre>
</td>
```

Tried Solution:

```
Elements rows = sdoc1.select("table.list > tbody > tr > td.label > span.header");
for (Element e : rows) 
{
System.out.println("All text:" + e.text());
}
```

there are 29 entries for SQL IDs. I should get values like below, but i'm not getting:

All Text: SQL ID: 7w1ahss5vuwv4
All Text: SQL ID: 7w1ahss5vuw4u

Comment: Is the rest of the HTML is same as the `tr` you've attached?

Comment: Yes.. Same Tr is repeated 13 times with different values

Comment: Very strange, Your query works fine for me. I'm using jsoup 1.11.3.

Comment: @TDG but I don’t see any elements stored in that array with specified pattern.

Comment: So the problem is not at the query. How do you get the html? Can you add the code that fetches the data from the server?